# rollup watch failed to resolve transform dependency

Tags: typescript, npm, bundle, rollup

I have a node project (namely A) that has the following dependencies:

```
A requires B (^1.2.0)
A requires C (^1.0.0)
C requires B (^1.0.0)
```

And the problem comes from that B dependency. For some reason, if I use rollup without using watch (`-w`), then everything is rolled up nicely. However, when I added watch (`-w`), then rollup starts to misbehave and throws this:

```
Error: Transform dependency node_modules/B/node_modules/C/index.ts does not exist.
```

Did I miss something here ? :( Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when using the `rollup-plugin-typescript2` library.

At first I did check the file existed and then add the file requested in the `include` file within the `tsconfig.json` to check if it worked.
It did work but the solution wasn't great.

Then I removed the `rpt2_cache` folder in the project workspace and tried again, all ok now.